# What is wrong with my Havel-Hakimi Algorithm code?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to practice my coding skill and I found a coding practice on Dailyprogrammer Reddit that uses Havel-Hakimi Algorithm (https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/bqy1cf/20190520_challenge_378_easy_the_havelhakimi/), but it keeps returning the wrong boolean.

I tried to check my process in every loop to make sure all the methods are doing the right jobs and the output is what I expected, yet it keeps returning the wrong boolean.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] answer = {16, 9, 9, 15, 9, 7, 9, 11, 17, 11, 4, 9, 12, 14, 14, 12, 17, 0, 3, 16};
    System.out.println(hh(answer));
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println(temp.size());
}

//This is the actual Havel-Hakimi Algorithm Method
public static boolean hh(int[] answer) {
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int n;
    for(int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        temp.add(answer[i]);
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) {
        if(temp.get(j) == 0)
            temp.remove(j);
    }

    if(temp.size() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    Collections.sort(temp);
    for(int t = 0; t < temp.size(); t++) {
    }
    n = temp.get(0);
    temp.remove(0);
    if(n > temp.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        temp.set(k, temp.get(k) - 1);
    }
    int[] newAnswer = new int[temp.size()];;
    for(int l = 0; l < temp.size(); l++) {
        newAnswer[l] = temp.get(l);
    }
    return hh(newAnswer);

}
```

Using the array provided in main method, "hh" method should return true but it returns false.

Comment: I think the problem is with `Collections.sort(temp)` as it sorts the collection in ascending order, while you want to sort it in descending order. You can use a custom comparer. I'm not sure but maybe you can do it like this `Collections.sort(temp, Collections.reverseOrder())`

Comment: what is that loop just after sorting `for (int t...`? Also I would not copy all values to `temp` and then remove all zeros; just skip the zeros.As Ammar already wrote, the main problem is that sorting is not done in descending order. variable `temp` in `main` is not really being used.

Comment: @Ammar Thank you so much that solved the problem for me! Can't believe I missed that

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Sorry that was the loop that supposed to have a println in there for me to check if the sorting was working. Also thank you for the advice and it's all working now!

Comment: no need for sorry,I just a note... also I would prefer to work just with lists, no arrays in that method (including argument); also try using an additional loop instead of recursion (`hh` not calling itself)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `Collections.sort(temp)`, it sorts the input collection in ascending order, while you want it to be sorted in descending order. You can use `Collections.sort(temp, Collections.reverseOrder())`

That was the logical problem in your code.

I should point out that some statements are unnecessary in your code (such as the `for` loop just after `Collections.sort(temp)`, it does nothing), other statements can be enhanced (such as the first two `for` loops, instead of copying the whole array, then filter it, why not just copy the needed elements?), you can also avoid using recursion by using a `while(true)` loop.

Here's a code that will help you solve your problem:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] answer = {16, 9, 9, 15, 9, 7, 9, 11, 17, 11, 4, 9, 12, 14, 14, 12, 17, 0, 3, 16};
    System.out.println(hh(answer));
}

//This is the actual Havel-Hakimi Algorithm Method
public static boolean hh(int[] answer) {
    while(true) {
        // Filter zero's from answer array 
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList(Arrays
                // get a Stream<Integer> from int[]
                .stream(answer)
                // filter zero's (this returns an IntStream)
                .filter(a -> a != 0)
                // reconvert it to Stream<Integer>
                .boxed()
                // Collect the stream as a List<Integer>
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        // Check the filtered array if it became empty after filtering
        if (temp.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Sort the filtered array in descending order
        Collections.sort(temp, Collections.reverseOrder());

        // Remove the first element (note that remove method returns the removed element)
        int n = temp.remove(0);

        // Check if the first removed element is larger than the new size of the array
        if (n > temp.size()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Reconstruct the input array for the next iteration
        answer = IntStream.range(0, temp.size())
                .map(i -> i < n ? temp.get(i) - 1 : temp.get(i))
                .toArray();
    }
}
```

If you're not familiar with `Streams` you can simply use `for` loops instead.